# Caching JSON: HTTP cache vs database

Tags: android, json, sqlite, http, caching

I'm working on an application that consumes JSON feed from the backend. By default, an HTTP request will be fired every time when the user accesses the application while being connected to the Internet, and if there's no network the data should be loaded from cache. I'm using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for networking, and I see two ways to implement caching: either use an [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) client configured to support caching, or create an SQLite database to store data. The second option is familiar to me, therefore looks more reliable, however there's a lot of overhead related to this approach. I've never really used HTTP caching, and I'd like to know whether it's sufficient to just rely on it for offline data viewing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right about SQLite, it is better approach which is to separate HTTP requests and access to actual data. Since it is feed, it is structured data. You can do following approach:

1. Http Requests -> JSON -> Parser -> SQLite DB insertion
2. CursorLoader ( Or custom any loader ) from SQLite DB -> List or any other adapters

This way, you always have access to data even if there is no internet. You can trigger HTTP poll any good time and update DB. On update/change have observer of content data to trigger loader and update UI if that's shown currently to user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I'm still not convinced that using a database is better than just making HTTP calls with a preconfigured cache. Retrofit makes it possible to make a network request and get the response in form of, say, List<Item>, so I don't really need another data structuring mechanism.

Comment: It really depends on the app's logic. If you cache JSON response, you will need parse it each time you read it. If you use global HTTP cache, you might ended up caching responses you do not need. Item class as you describe is required in any case, if you get it from JSON or from SQLite. As I said, it is really decision based on how the app will work.

Comment: So I guess main drawbacks of HTTP caching solution are less control over the cache and having to parse JSON every time it's extracted from cache?

Comment: Thanks again, I need to consider these details to select the best solution.